# Could use some advice on jQuery each function on a associative multidimensional array

Tags: php, jquery, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I'm working on a jQuery `.get` that will send a value to the server to compare against an array which will then get encoded into a json format as the responses. Below is the code (jQuery and PHP zend). I'm not sure if my problem is with identifying the keys and values or if it is the syntax. Is there away to view the raw json data echoed by my php controller?

```
   $.get( 
    "/ed/macro",
       {value: singleValues},
         function(data) {
             $.each(data, function(key,value1){
         $.each(data.value1[0], function(key,value2){

           $('#stage').html("data");; 
       });
   });
    },"json");

   $select = $this->getDbTable()->select();
   $select->from('sub');
   $resultSet = $this->getDbTable()->fetchall($select);
   $data   = array();

   foreach ($resultSet as $row) {
        $entry = new Application_Model_Subdiscipline();
        $entry->setIdSub($row->idsubdiscipline)
              ->setSub($row->subdiscipline)
              ->setDescription($row->description);

        $data[] = $entry;
   }

   return $data;
}

public function macAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest()->getParam('value');

    // acti
    $sub = new Application_Model_Sub();
    $fetch = $sub->fetchAll($request);
    $jsonObject = Zend_Json::encode($fetch);
    echo $jsonObject;  
      // action body
}
```

Comment: To view the object print_r in PHP and console.log in Javascript

Answer (score 0):

To view the object `print_r`in PHP and `console.log` in Javascript. Or as Sam said, after the JS has called it, look in Net to see what was sent.

Assuming that you are echoing a json string after telling your server to tell the browser it is json with `header("Content-type: application/json");` your problem is probably here

```
$.each(data, function(key,value1){
     $.each(data.value1[0], function(key,value2){
```

`data.value1` isn't what you're dealing with there, it's `value1`. I'm assuming `value1` **IS** an array, and you're picking the first element in it `value1[0]` to then iterate?

```
$.each(data, function(key,value1){
     $.each(value1[0], function(key,value2){
```

Or maybe you're after

```
$.each(data, function(key,value1){
     $.each(value1, function(key,value2){
```

Please echo the object and show it to us.

Comment: If you're opening a javascript console, it's easier to just check the network request, no?